# Diluer pour un gaz

Tags: vocabulaire, science

Je ne crois pas que *diluer* se prête à cet usage. Si ce n'est pas le cas existe-t-il un verbe analogue mais qui ne serait pas exclusif au liquide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il me semble juste d'utiliser *diluer* pour un gaz, même si il serait peut être préférable d'utiliser *diffuser*. Il se peut également que *mélanger deux (ou plus) gaz* soit plus approprié selon les circonstances.

Il est vrai que cela sonne plus juste pour un liquide ou une solution (en chimie), mais il faut penser que l'emploi de diluer un liquide n'a pas vraiment de sens si l'on ne précise pas dans quoi. Diluer une solution d'éthanol dans de l'eau par exemple.

On peut remarquer que l'on parle aussi de *solution diluée* pour dire peu concentrée, sans préciser dans quoi mais cela est implicite de par l'utilisation de *solution*.

Pour rester dans le domaine de la chimie et de la physique, on dirait qu'une odeur se diffuse (ou se répand mais cela est plus littéraire) et le mécanisme physique derrière ce phénomène s'appelle la diffusion (avec les équations de la diffusion, les coefficients de diffusion, etc.). Par extension on peut donc parler de diffusion pour un gaz (généralement dans l'air ou dans un autre gaz pour certains cas particuliers).

Enfin dans un sens plus figuré on peut diluer de nombreuses choses non matérielles.

Comment: _Diluer_ est une opération qui réduit la proportion d'un élément dans un mélange (c'est donc aussi valable pour les gaz que pour les liquides et les solides). _Diffuser_ signifie _migrer_ selon un certain gradient: c'est un phénomène naturel. On peut laisser un gaz se diluer par diffusion, mais les deux termes ne sont pas interchangeables.

Answer (score 2):

*[Diluer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/diluer)* peut s'employer :

- pour des liquides :  « diluer l'acide dans l'eau »
- pour des gaz : « la mauvaise odeur s'est diluée dans l'air »
- mais également pour des choses plus abstraites, comme du texte : « les arguments essentiels sont dilués dans le texte »

Comment: Les liens vers *atilf.fr* sont liés à une session et ne fonctionnent pas pour les autres utilisateurs. Il faut utiliser le portail du *cnrtl.fr* si possible.

Comment: Au temps pour moi. Malheureusement le portail du *cnrtl.fr* me redirige vers l'*atilf.fr* quand je veux faire une recherche sur un mot. Tant pis, je supprime le lien.

Comment: Le chemin depuis la page d'accueil est un peu détourné, tu peux accéder au TLF sur cnrtl.fr via http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/

Answer (score 1):

**Diluer ne peut s'appliquer qu'à un liquide** d'après les dictionnaires de référence, qui sont fidèles à l'étymologie latine (*diluere* = détremper, laver, dissoudre, délayer).

Il en est de même des quasi-synonymes :  allonger, délayer, dissoudre, étendre, mouiller.

**Le mot est utile**, car tous les corps ne sont pas solubles dans un liquide donné (cf l'air dans le mercure), et deux liquides ne sont pas toujours miscibles (cf la vinaigrette).

**La question ne se pose pas pour les gaz** : ils se mélangent de toutes façons d'eux-mêmes (sauf mélange réactif, auquel cas ils se combinent). Une odeur se dissipe, mais ne se dilue pas.

Le sens peut bien entendu être figuratif, dans le domaine des idées.

Comment: "La question ne se pose pas pour les gaz" puisque la distinction n'est pas nécessaire quel verbe employer? Dissiper?

Comment: Je ne suis pas tout à fait d'accord. On dit qu'une odeur se dissipe, mais chimiquement, elle se dilue dans énormément d'air, non ?

Comment: @Knu : pour les gaz, j'ai dit, peut-être elliptiquement, que de toutes façons ils se mélangent (sauf réaction chimique, auquel cas ils se combinent en un nouveau produit par ex. H² + Cl² -> 2 HCl). L'odeur vient soit d'un gaz par ex. H²S, qui se mélange jusqu'à ce soit dans tellement d'air que la concentration devienne trop infime pour l'odorat, qui n'y est plus sensible, soit de particules comme un aérosol, qui se dispersent jusqu'à ce que, de même, il n'y en ait plus assez pour être détectées.

Comment: @Knu. (suite, le commentaire était trop long pour être envoyé en une fois) De plus, le nez "se fatigue", on ne fait plus attention au bout d'un certain temps à une odeur qui frapperait quelqu'un entrant dans la pièce. Dans une prairie de fleurs par exemple, il faut que le vent recharge incessamment de particules l'air, pour que l'impression persiste.

Comment: @Thibault je voulais vous envoyer simultanément les commentaires précédents, mais un seul destinataire est autorisé.

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord pour dire que diluer ne peut s'appliquer qu'à un liquide, parce qu'en chimie, ça peut aussi s'appliquer à un gaz, voire à un solide, signifiant _réduire la concentration_.